# React perspective animation trouble

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

I have some trouble with my React perspective animation. I need each picture to "follow" the cursor, it turned out only that they move all together when the cursor moves around the window, but I need each one individually when the cursor moves within its own div.services_pic. Tried using document.getElementsByClassName('services_pic') instead of window, but no luck. Would appreciate an explanation, thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
// import './ServiceStyle.css';
import './ServiceStyle.scss';
import dev from './img/1.svg';
import qa from './img/2.svg';
import integ from './img/3.svg';
import consalt from './img/4.svg';
import mobile from './img/5.svg';


export default class Service extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    this.state = {
      offsetX: "",
      offsetY: "",
      friction: 1 / 32,
    };
    this._mouseMove = this._mouseMove.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this._mouseMove);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this._mouseMove);
  }
  _mouseMove(e) {
    let followX = window.innerWidth / 2 - e.clientX;
    let followY = window.innerHeight / 2 - e.clientY;

    let x = 0,
      y = 0;
    x += (-followX - x) * this.state.friction;
    y += (followY - y) * this.state.friction;
    this.setState({
      offsetX: x,
      offsetY: y,
    });
  }
    render() {
      let offset = {
        transform: `perspective(600px)
                    rotateY(${this.state.offsetX}deg)
                    rotateX(${this.state.offsetY}deg)`,
      
                    
      };
        return (
            <div className="service">
        <h1>сервисы и услуги</h1> 
        <div className="service-wrapper">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
              <div className="col-4 service_item">
                <div className="anim_pic" style={offset}><img className="anim_img" src={dev} alt="software"></img></div>
                <p className="service_text">Разработка программного <br /> обеспечения</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-4">
                <div className="anim_pic" style={offset}><img className="anim_img" src={qa} alt="QA" /></div>
                <p className="service_text">QA-решения</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-4">
                <div className="anim_pic" style={offset}><img className="anim_img" src={integ} alt="integration"  /></div>
                <p className="service_text">Интеграционные решения</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
              <div className="col-4">
                <div className="anim_pic" style={offset}><img className="anim_img" src={consalt} alt="consulting" /></div>
                <p className="service_text">Консалтинг</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-4">
                <div className="anim_pic" style={offset}><img className="anim_img" src={mobile} alt="mobile"  /></div>
                <p className="service_text">Мобильные разработки</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        )
    }
}
```